# Как font-size влияет на производительность страницы?

Tags: html, css, css3

У меня есть страница на которой много табличных данных, есть анимированные чекбоксы и прочая ерунда, для текста в таблице выставлен font-size: 10px;

Почему если выставить font-size: 10px анимация тормозит, если оставить по умолчанию всё отрабатывает гораздо быстрее??? Как это работает и что с этим делать? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На данный момент, есть всего два свойства, которые можно анимировать безболезненно — это `transform` и `opacity`, потому что они выносятся на отдельный слой и не вызывают этап Layout в так называемом конвейере пикселей. Схема конвейера вот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда вы меняете размер шрифта, то это, очевидно, влияет на макет абсолютно всех блоков на странице и за каждый кадр браузер пытается пройти этапы: Layout, Paint, Composite. Отсюда и тормоза.

[Источник](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/?hl=ru).